# How to POST only a few fields of JSON request body from a DTO to a URL spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot:

I have a DTO with 4 fields.
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3",
"key4": "value4"
}

I am doing a PostMapping(@RequestBody DTO dto)

I have to make a POST call to a URL which requires only key2,key3 and key4 in POST body.
key1 is a part of the URI, meaning:

POST to https://domain/app/"value1"/test/something
POST Body being as below
{
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3",
"key4": "value4"
}

Can someone please help guide how this can be done.

Comment: This should work withtout change. Do you get an exception?

Comment: I get a "400 Bad request" since the post doesn't expect the key1:value1, if I modify my DTO to post with body  "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "key4": "value4" }, it works.

Comment: But I have key1:value1 which I am using in the POST URL itself, so my post body construct should have my ditto minus the key1:value1

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sometimes API provider can use F5 server to define set of rules for incoming requests. It happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **@PathVariable** annotation

```
PostMapping(@PathVariable("value1") String value1, @RequestBody DTO dto)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you provide a way to retrieve the value from dto and send it to POST call URI and also send only {"key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "key4": "value4" } to the POST URL as a body.

Comment: While creating the URI you can just append or add your value into the URI from the dto object.

Answer (score 1):

Create another new DTO object which should have only required fields and using modelMapper map to your new request DTO.

add this dependency to your pom.xml (use latest version possible)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a new dto

```
Class NewDto{

 private String key2;
 private String key3;
 private String key4;

 //getters and setters
}
```

Then in the controller

```
@PostMapping("") //add your entry point
public ResponseEntity<?> method(@RequestBody DTO dto){

 String key1 = dto.getKey1();
 ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
 NewDto newDto = mapper.map(dto, NewDto.class);

 //now this newDto contains only required fields
 // then use key1 in uri and add newDto to request body and call post URI

}
```

Suppose if you willing to use ObjectMapper, You need to use @JsonIgnore on the properties. But i will suggest to use ModelMapper.

Answer (score 0):

The URL can be ***/topic/{key1}*** I do not know why you need extra ***/test/something*** appended here. If you want you may add extra ***/test/something*** to the route.

**NOTE:** ***The topic in the route is referring to the controller or the group name of the API here.***

You may have **TopicService** created to deal with the crud operations and further if you are using **JPA hibernate** from the service by creating a repository.

The **Topic Controller** can handle the incoming requests with the spring annotations.

***@RequestMapping*** is used to map the appropriate request to this controller method. 
And you can use spring enum called ***RequestMethod*** which holds different types of HTTP methods in it.
***@RequestBody*** consumes the (post method) Incoming Request's body which here, in this case, is accepted as Topic which will contain *(key2, key3, and key4)*. 
You should have the Topic class (DTO) defined with all its appropriate fields and also TopicService with appropriate crud operation methods.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/topics/{key1}")
public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic, @PathVariable String key1) {
    topicService.saveOrUpdateTopic(topic, key1);
}
```

Let me know if you need more clarity I can create a sample app and share it with you.
Thanks!

Comment: excellent, thanks for the explanation, I tried the model mapper method and it worked.